# Understanding coxme model results with 1 or 2 factors

Tags: survival, cox-model

I'm confused about the outcomes of two mixed-effects cox proportional hazard models on the same data set.

In my experiment, I'm investigating the survival of insects that are exposed to two different chemicals (either to one or to both combined) in a full-factorial design. Let's say the chemicals are "A" and "B". The insects were kept in groups (-> I have to include groups as random term in my models).

For each individual insect, I noted the number of days it survived before death (days.survived). For censoring (status), I used 1=censored, 2=dead.

I analysed my data in two ways:

1. with the 4-level factor "treatment" as response variable (1 factor analysis). The levels are "A", "B", "both" and "control"
2. with two 2-level factors, "Presence_A" (+A if A was applied,-A otherwise), "Presence_B" (+B if B was applied, -B otherwise".

I run my models as follows:

```
fit1 <- coxme(Surv(days.survived,status) ~ treatment + (1|group), data = survival)
fit2 <- coxme(Surv(days.survived,status) ~ A*B + (1|group), data = survival)
```

When looking at the results, I noted that the coefficients and p-values for the individual treatment levels in fit1 (e.g. "A") are exactly the same as for the ones in fit2 (e.g. "Presence_A:+A)

```
fit1:
Model:  Surv(days.survived, status) ~ treatment + (1 | group) 
Fixed coefficients
                                coef exp(coef)  se(coef)     z    p
A                           --------- 1.5       --------  ----- 0.2
B                           --------- 1.4       --------  ----- 0.5
both                        --------- ---       -------- ------ ---



fit2
Model:  Surv(days.survived, status) ~ A * B + (1 | group) 
Fixed coefficients
                                coef exp(coef)  se(coef)     z    p
presence_A+A                --------- 1.5       --------  ----- 0.2
presence_B+B                --------- 1.4       --------  ----- 0.5
presence_A+A:presence_B+B   --------- ---       -------- ------ ---
```

I think I'm missing something important here. Because for me it makes no sense that the results should be identical. E.g. in the case the 2-factor analysis, presence_A+A refers to all treatments where A is present (treatments "A" and "both"). So +A basically compares treatments "A" & "both" vs. treatments "B" & "control". Whereas in the 1-factor analysis, a treatment (e.g. "A") group is compared to the "control". So even the underlying sample sizes are different.

Can anyone explain to me how these models can produce the same outputs? I also tried something similar with coxph, and got the same outcome. In the end, I'd be really interested to see the "main" effect of chemical A or B, but I don't really trust the analysis right now.

Thank you very much for your help!

All the best,
Asuka

Answer (score 3):

I will let others on this forum answer your question, but wanted to comment on something that you may find useful.

If you are ultimately interested in the "main" effects of A and B, then you should consider using the *Anova()* function from the **car** package of R with the appropriate *type* option for your setting, which will be a choice among type II or type III. This function would need to be applied to your *fit2* model, which includes an interaction between A and B.

If you simply apply the *anova* function to your coxme model (note the lowercase a in its name), you will end up performing a type I (or sequential) anova, which is not what you need.

This nice post explains why you may want to consider a type III anova in your case (though ultimately you have to decide what makes most sense for your setting):

https://towardsdatascience.com/anovas-three-types-of-estimating-sums-of-squares-don-t-make-the-wrong-choice-91107c77a27a?gi=25c0f9e695cc

The post is titled **ANOVA’s three types of estimating Sums of Squares: don’t make the wrong choice!** and is written by Joos Korstanje for *Towards Data Science*.

The R commands you would therefore need are:

```
library(car)

Anova(fit2, type = "III")
```

**Note:**

Another nice post is **https://mcfromnz.wordpress.com/2011/03/02/anova-type-iiiiii-ss-explained/**.

P.S. Can you list **all** estimated coefficients for your output? Some are missing.

Comment: Dear Isabella
Thank you very much for your answer. I didn't even know you can perform Anova on a coxme object. I thought I'd simply present the hazard ratios from my model output as results. And state e.g. that the hazard is higher/lower if chemical A or B are applied. I normally only work with (generalized) linear mixed effects models, and am not yet used to survival analysis. But from that, I'm familiar with the different kinds of anova.
Sorry for not putting my whole output into the question, I just wanted to illustrate that the coefficients are identical in both models. 
All the best :)